# jazz_hands gem breaks history in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've started using `jazz_hands` to make my Rails console more useful, but now line/history editing is broken. When I run over the end of the line (ie, wrap), or use up arrow to go into history, the output is garbled.

Terminal settings are fine for everything else, Ubuntu 12. Any ideas? I'm hoping it's something simple and I'm not the first developer to bump into this, but there's nothing in the FAQ, or in the various related Gems (pry etc), and I'm loathe to raise a bug on the project until I check this isn't a well known issue.

Comment: What happens if you don't run over the end of the line, does everything work fine then?

Comment: It's very odd, it's fine until I hit the end of line but the character position it goes mad at is NOT the actual terminal size end of line. Which is why I'm hoping it's a VT100 vs xterm type problem?

Comment: I have the same issue on a Mac, using  the default terminal & ITerm2 :(

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in the latest update, but here's a few workarounds if for some reason you can't update.

https://github.com/nixme/jazz_hands/issues/1